# How to add plus minus symbol to a bootstrap accordion along with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap accordion in angular js. The panels are opening If I click on the heading directly but I need to add plus/minus symbols for each heading. Please help me out in achieving the functionality like If I click plus icon, panel should be open and If I click on minus symbol, the panel should be closed. Thanks in advance.

Sorry, I Cannot able to add fiddle or plunker as the data is coming from my local database.

```html
 <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" class="accordion-data">
            <uib-accordion-group heading="title from database" ng-repeat="values are coming from database">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row row-head">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item-head accordion-content" ng-repeat="values are coming from database">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" >data from database
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 service-data">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                                        <input type="number" name="times" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check" ng-readonly="true" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check" ng-readonly="true" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check" ng-readonly="true" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </uib-accordion-group>
        </uib-accordion>
```

Comment: For Plunkr / JSFiddle, it's really easy to mock data with JavaScript object literals in AngularJS. Just `$scope.myData = { /*data*/ }`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics about your implementation, but you could make use of the CSS `:before` pseudo-element like I have done in this [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opaoqgp4/).

If you have a way of selecting the accordion header by the open/closed state, then you can do something similar to this:

```
.accordion li.open:before {
  content: '- ';
}
.accordion li.closed:before {
  content: '+ ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

glyphicon glyphicon-plusIf you want to handle this in javascript, you could use the `collapse` event described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

`shown.bs.collapse` will fire when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). 
`hidden.bs.collapse` will fire when a collapse element has been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
$('#yourCollapseDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-plus");
});

$('#yourCollapseDiv').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
});
```

It uses [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) to display the + and -